# How can I capture video from different windows using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture

I have a proprietary IPTV player, and my goal is to capture a video from this player's several windows simultaneously. I'm able to do that with ffmpeg and VLC (for instance) using vlc windows' titles like this:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="german.avi - VLC media player" -b:v 3M  germ.flv


ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="2015-05-10 Sportscene.mkv - VLC media player" -b:v 3M  scot.flv
```

and so on.

But when I run 2 or more instances of that proprietary player, all of its windows' titles are similar. So the question is how can I specify which window's video in which file to record?